# How to embed the consistent data in HTML Email

Tags: html-email, exchangewebservices

How could I have something like `<b>Case ID</b> : <span id="caseDtl_caseId">00004</span>` in HTML email consistently? I have found that when the email was replied, the `id` attribute is lost. Or is there the better way to retrieve the information from non-formed email?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't use the Message Headers instead, eg if your generating the Message you could set/store the MessageID of the message you send and then use the In-Reply-To header to identify responses https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4021#page-10, Or use the Thread-Index/ConversationId properties like the Mail Clients do to track messages in a thread.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: I cannot use ConversationId because my office is using Exchange Web Server 2007. But the In-Reply-To and References headers is a good idea.